# Duplicates using preceding data

Tags: r, dataframe, date, duplicates

Hi I need to find duplicates, I have attached an image of the dataset and an example of a duplicate. Same id, and same result with preceding dates.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Dataset Screengrab

[image]

```
structure(list(id = c(1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 
1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 
1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 
1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 1010001, 
1010001, 1010001, 1010001), DateCollected = structure(c(1145664000, 
1145750400, 1145836800, 1145923200, 1146009600, 1146096000, 1146096000, 
1146096000, 1146096000, 1146096000, 1146096000, 1146182400, 1146268800, 
1146355200, 1146441600, 1146528000, 1146614400, 1146700800, 1146787200, 
1146787200, 1146787200, 1146787200, 1146787200, 1146787200, 1146873600, 
1146960000, 1147046400, 1147132800, 1147219200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Test = c("Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", 
"Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)", "Tacrolimus (FK506)"
), Result = c(3, 4.1, 5.9, 8.1, 4.6, 7, 7.8, 11.2, 18.1, 18.4, 
27, 4, 7.8, 8.4, 8.4, 6.1, 6.8, 5.4, 5.4, 6.5, 6.7, 8.1, 14.2, 
32.4, 7.2, 8.6, 8.9, 7.2, 9.6), Units = c("ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", 
"ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", 
"ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", 
"ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", "ug/L", 
"ug/L", "ug/L")), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: are you looking for duplicates only for the previous date or anywhere for the same 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function to calculate difference between the value of `Result` and return row indices when a duplicate is found.

```
find_duplicates <- function(x) {
  inds <- which(diff(x) == 0)
  sort(unique(c(inds, inds + 1)))
}
```

We can apply this function by group.

To get duplicate rows we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(find_duplicates(Result))

#      id DateCollected       Test               Result Units
#    <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>               <dbl> <chr>
#1 1010001 2006-04-30 00:00:00 Tacrolimus (FK506)    8.4 ug/L 
#2 1010001 2006-05-01 00:00:00 Tacrolimus (FK506)    8.4 ug/L 
#3 1010001 2006-05-04 00:00:00 Tacrolimus (FK506)    5.4 ug/L 
#4 1010001 2006-05-05 00:00:00 Tacrolimus (FK506)    5.4 ug/L
```

To get an additional flag column we can use :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(is_duplicate = row_number() %in% find_duplicates(Result))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can group by 'id' and create a flag by checking the `lag` or `lead` of the adjacent 'Result'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(flag= Result == lag(Result)|Result == lead(Result)) %>%
   filter(flag)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   id [1]
#      id DateCollected       Test               Result Units flag 
#    <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>               <dbl> <chr> <lgl>
#1 1010001 2006-04-30 00:00:00 Tacrolimus (FK506)    8.4 ug/L  TRUE 
#2 1010001 2006-05-01 00:00:00 Tacrolimus (FK506)    8.4 ug/L  TRUE 
#3 1010001 2006-05-04 00:00:00 Tacrolimus (FK506)    5.4 ug/L  TRUE 
#4 1010001 2006-05-05 00:00:00 Tacrolimus (FK506)    5.4 ug/L  TRUE
```